# Como resolver esse conflito de dependências?

Tags: android-studio

Criei um novo projeto para uns testes mas está aparecendo este erro

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.

> Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Comment: Não é uma solução, mas o meu eu só resolvi copiando o meu arquivo app de uma aplicação que estava funcionando para a que está com problema. Dá uma olhada nesse link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999124/resolved-versions-for-app-22-0-0-and-test-app-21-0-3-differ Fiz tudo nele, mas nao deu. Se descobrir a solução coloca aqui por favor :D

Comment: Coloque parte do gradle, fica melhor pra te responder